# php and html framework to show paginated table with search input

Tags: php, postgresql, yii

I have created my own framework which is getting query from `PostgreSQL` database like:

```
$q="select * from employee";
$rows = $db->query($q)->fetchall();
```

in `$row` i have 3k long array.  Now when I prepared page (using `JavaScript` libraries to paginate) to show content of this variable source code of the page is 10k+ lines long so the downloading it by user browser is quite long. I would like to optimize it.

Second step was using `$_GET` parameters to control `offset` value in `psql` statement. This way loading of the page is much faster. But managing table content and setting correctly search engine in table and sorting is quite difficult.

I have searched for a framework or library which would allow me to achieve my goal I have found about `Yii` framework and the exact example of this what I want to get is showed here:

[Yii example of GridView](http://www.yiiplayground.com/index.php?r=UiModule/dataview/gridView)

But this framework looks pretty complex and I wonder if maybe there is any other library/framework that is destined only to show `$array` as `HTML` table?

Comment: Yii is actually pretty simple as a framework. Also look into Laravel, which is simple too. Don't miss Symfony, either: more complex, but also a lot more configurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Propositions of @Andresch and @greg were really helpful, however I decided not to mixing frameworks inside one project.

Solution for me Was `DataTables` -> [jQuery library for displaying tables](https://datatables.net/) it contains everything I want including `Ajax sources`. Configuration is also really easy and looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '../ajax/sources/databaseconnector.php'
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

[Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) from sensiolabs is a micro framework based on symfony2. It is less complex than yii.
Check out this [list of microframeworks](http://phptrends.com/category/9).

Answer (score 0):

I use [Pomm](http://www.pomm-project.org) for this kind of problems:

```
$row = $myEntityMap->paginateFindWhere($condition, $values, null, $rpp, $page);
```

See [documentation](http://www.pomm-project.org/documentation/manual-1.2#pagers) for more details. You can use Pomm with any framework you like or without framework since it is a stand alone library. It actually has adapters for Symfony and Silex.